# unable to join server to existing domain in azure within virtual network

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, azure

I have created a Virtual Network on Azure and have created two VM's within the Virtual network, with IP's **10.0.0.4** and **10.0.0.5**. I have added Active Directory role to a one of the VM's and promoted it to Domain Controller role. I am trying to the other VM to the existing domain (mydomain.com) but I get an error stating that the "**AD Domain Controller could not be contacted**". What may be the cause of this? I checked that the Gateway and Subnet mask of the two servers match.

Comment: Is the other VM using the new DC for DNS? If not, then that's probably the problem.

Comment: i haven't set anything like that. how can I do that? even the DC obtains DNS automatically

Comment: https://abhijitw.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/best-practices-for-dns-client-settings-on-domain-controller

Comment: i checked the ipv4 dns address in the network properties. they are the same on both servers

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. Are they both set to use the DC for DNS? If not, then that's the problem. AD members should not use public DNS servers for DNS. They should only use AD DNS servers for DNS.

Comment: i assigned a preferred DNS Server to the DNS as 127.0.0.2 and alternate as 127.0.0.3 and set the other VM to also use those DNS Servers. Still not able to join it to the domain

Comment: Oh my. On the DC use the DC's actual ip address as preferred and use 127.0.0.1 as secondary. On the client use the DC's actual ip address as primary and leave the secondary blank.

Comment: it worked. thanks..:)
add as an answer so i can upvote the answer

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: Yes Naba Das, Trondh, jennelle crothers posts have it right. I was following the dev\test environment setup here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/base-configuration-dev-test-environment and it mentioned nothing about configuring the virtual network from the azure portal. I guessed (incorrectly) to change the DNS on the VM network settings, not the virtual network. This made it unable to RDP, so I had to undo it via the serial console. I moved on to other parts of setup then I ran across this post a while later. That did it, worked immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your DNS configuration is the problem.

On the DC use the DC's actual ip address as the preferred DNS server and use 127.0.0.1 as the secondary DNS server. On the client use the DC's actual ip address as the primary DNS server and leave the secondary DNS server blank.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please make sure you dont make any changes to IP/DNS records inside VM. If you do you will not longer be able to RDP to the machine and have to re-built it.
2. Solution is very simple. Go to AZURE portal and select the VNET to which the CLIENT(END POINTS) belongs. Go to DNS and change it from Microsoft DNS to Custom and put the IP of the Domain controller.
3. save the settings and reboot the machine in that VNET.
   4.Try to add to the domain again and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You control DNS for the network in network settings.

1. Make sure your DC has a static internal ip address so that it doesn't aquire a new ip address upn reboot
2. In the virtual network settings in the azure portal (you need to do this using manage.windowsazure.com afaik) configure the vnet's DNS to point to your DC's static internal ip address
3. Reboot your to-be-member server. Running ipconfig on it should confirm that it now uses the DC as its DNS server and you shoulw be able to go ahead and join it to the domain.
4. For some reason external domains resolve a bit fishy when set up like this, so it's a good idea to set up a forwarder on your DC's DNS server to point to some well-known public dns such as 8.8.8.8 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Do not adjust the DNS or DHCP properties of your VMs in Azure. You just need to make sure that the virtual network you created in Azure has your internal IP address of the domain controller listed. In this case, 10.0.0.4. This way your second machine can located the first DC to join the domain.

From that point on, your DC will be responsible for resolving all DNS requests, just like it would have to do on an on-prem network.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure VNet you have to set a Custom DNS server to your DC which is 10.0.0.4. So go to the network interface --> DNS servers --> Custome --> Private IP of DNS and save